# In Monster My Neighbor, how is the Rumor card resolved?

Tags: monster-my-neighbor

In Monster My Neighbor the Rumor card states:

> Each player draws 1 card from the hand of the player to their right.

How is this card resolved?

I assumed that the player playing the card would draw a card from the player to their right, and then each player, clockwise, would follow, but the rules doesn't clarify this.

Comment: If someone with sufficient rights could create and put a **monster-my-neighbor** tag for this, instead of **reference**, that would be swell. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this thread on [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1594356/are-actions-stated-rumour-and-gossip-simultaneous) this card is resolved simultaneoously. I'd say you can resolve it in turn order if you want to, just set aside newly drawn cards.